# I am not getting sonar in the web browser

Tags: sonarqube

I installed sonar server in my opensuse 11.4 64 bit system.I configured my database and started sonar server from the terminal.Then I took my web browser and opened `http://localhost:9000/sonar`.But I am getting the following screen.
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /sonar. Reason:

```
SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

Why this is happening?See my error log below.Anyone Please help me

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 | 2012-12-04 14:20:39.615:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 | 2012-12-04 14:20:39.652:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/12/04 14:20:39 | 2012-12-04 14:20:39.815:INFO::NO JSP Support for /sonar, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2012.12.04 14:20:40 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  Sonar Server / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:41 INFO  o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase  Starting embedded database on port 9001 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9001/sonar
2012.12.04 14:20:41 INFO  o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase  Embedded database started. Data stored in: /home/tom/sonar-3.3.2/data
2012.12.04 14:20:41 WARN  o.s.c.p.DefaultDatabase  H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2012.12.04 14:20:41 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9001/sonar
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Sonar home: /home/tom/sonar-3.3.2
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Deploy dir: /home/tom/sonar-3.3.2/war/sonar-server/deploy
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins...
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin English Pack / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Surefire / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Duplications / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin PMD / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Core / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Java / 1.0 / 5ac4cf695248bc7385cb3377216cd86340bda0b0
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Cobertura / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 1.0 / 5ac4cf695248bc7385cb3377216cd86340bda0b0
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Design / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 3.3.2 / 614afef12ae442ad50831a7bc604664378e31088
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins done: 152 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.s.p.ApplicationDeployer  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Start components...
2012.12.04 14:20:43 INFO  o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector  Initializing Hibernate
2012.12.04 14:20:45 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2012.12.04 14:20:45 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy GWT plugins...
2012.12.04 14:20:45 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.core.testdetailsviewer.TestsViewer to /home/tom/sonar-3.3.2/war/sonar-server/deploy/gwt
2012.12.04 14:20:45 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.libraries.LibrariesPage to /home/tom/sonar-3.3.2/war/sonar-server/deploy/gwt
2012.12.04 14:20:45 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy org.sonar.plugins.design.ui.page.DesignPage to /home/tom/sonar-3.3.2/war/sonar-server/deploy/gwt
2012.12.04 14:20:45 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Deploy GWT plugins done: 131 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:45 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Load metrics...
2012.12.04 14:20:47 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  cleaning alert thresholds...
2012.12.04 14:20:47 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Load metrics done: 2085 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:47 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [findbugs/java]...
2012.12.04 14:20:48 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  414 rules
2012.12.04 14:20:49 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [findbugs/java] done: 1110 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:49 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [checkstyle/java]...
2012.12.04 14:20:49 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  129 rules
2012.12.04 14:20:49 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [checkstyle/java] done: 789 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:49 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd/java]...
2012.12.04 14:20:50 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  232 rules
2012.12.04 14:20:50 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd/java] done: 1077 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:50 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd-unit-tests/java]...
2012.12.04 14:20:50 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  10 rules
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [pmd-unit-tests/java] done: 160 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [squid/java]...
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  17 rules
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [squid/java] done: 187 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [common-java/java]...
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  4 rules
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [common-java/java] done: 27 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Disable deprecated user rules...
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Disable deprecated user rules done: 91 ms
2012.12.04 14:20:51 INFO  o.s.s.s.RegisterNewProfiles  Register Quality Profiles...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using the standalone version of Sonar, which is running on Jetty at "http://localhost:9000" URL by default (there's no '/sonar' application context).

So unless you modified Jetty deployment config, you should go and have a look at "http://localhost:9000" and not "http://localhost:9000/sonar".